# About the distance between two disjoint sets

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

I have to give an example of two nonempty sets A and B such that $A∩B=∅$  and
*d*$(A,B)=0$.

Could somebody give me a hint?

Comment: $(-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: Any non-empty sets, or non-empty *closed* sets?

Comment: any non-empty sets

Comment: Another example: $\,\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}\,$.

Comment: @JacobSchwartz So $A$ and $X\setminus A$ for ANY nontrivial $A$ is good.

Comment: The graph of $y=e^x$ and the graph of $y=0$.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke If the space $X$ is connected.

Comment: $A=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ and $B=\{1.1,2.01,3.001,\dots\}.$

Comment: @bof Yes. The discrete metric is a total counterexample. :-)

Comment: The big point here is that the distance being zero can be rephrased as that there is no *strictly positive* distance which is less than it.